# A regex to split a file path

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex to split a path as shown in the following scheme:

```
Path:        c:\foo\bar\baz.txt
Root name:   c:
Parent path: c:\foo\bar
Filename:    baz.txt
Stem:        baz
Extension:   txt
```

Here is what I have. The problem is that it doesn't work when I have a filename without an extension:

```
^(([aA-zZ]:)\\(?:[^:]+))\\(([^\\]+)\.([^\.]+))$
```

I can change it to

```
^(([aA-zZ]:)\\(?:[^:]+))\\(([^\\]+)(\.([^\.]+))?)$
```

but it doesn't split a filename to a stem and an extension.

Comment: you cant do this with a simple regex. Of course you can split the string on `/` delimiter but grouping into logical units cannot be done with a simple regex

Comment: for example `([a-z]:)?((\\[^\\]+)*?)\\([a-z.]+)` can split into logical units but is not recommended

Comment: Regex sounds like a bad idea here. Why not using string.indexof / substring in your used language?

Comment: how the output look like ?

Comment: @Leonardo What you mean? Cheers.

Comment: what do you want in the end.. i mean input -> output , do want them in capturing groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lazy quantifier and an optional group:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]:)(?:\\[^:]+)?)\\(([^\\\n]+?)(?:\.([^.\n]+))?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJ95IA/2)

It is important to make `([^\\]+?)` a lazy match to avoid it matching too much when next non-capture group i.e. `(?:\.([^.\n]+))?` is an optional match.

Comment: Here is a test: https://regexr.com/52tst. As you see, groups 3 and 4 are both `baz`. Isn't it possible to make one of them empty to avoid duplication?

Comment: Group 3 represents `Filename` and Group 4 represents `Stem`. In the 2nd case only extension is empty and `Filename` and `Stem` values are same. So not sure why one of these should be empty..

Comment: After some thinking I tend to agree with you :)

Comment: Maybe you could slightly improve it so that it will work for paths like `c:\foo.txt` and `c:\foo` as well?

Comment: Tested with `c:\foo\bar\aaa.txt`, `c:\foo\bar\aaa`, `c:\aaa.txt`, `c:\aaa`. Works for me: `^(([a-zA-Z]:)(?:\\[^:]+)?)\\(([^\\]+?)(?:\.([^.\n]+))?)$`.

Comment: That's great,  let me test and then I will modify my answer.

Comment: And another one improvement: `^(([a-zA-Z]:)(?:\\[^:]+)?)\\(([^\\\n]+?)(?:\.([^.\n]+))?)$`. It will stop this one issue: https://regexr.com/532td

Comment: I have discovered an issue related to dot files (dot files are most common on Unix-like operating systems, but they are also created on Windows by some cross-platform software). In case of a dot file, e.g. `.file`, Windows treats `file` as an extension. The regex treats the whole thing (i.e., `.file`) as a stem and "nothing" as an extension. Some people may prefer the regex to work in the same way as Windows, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have to leave for some work. Meanwhile please check if this works out: https://regex101.com/r/QJ95IA/3 I will follow up later.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. The only minor issue there is that in case of `.file` the 4th group is empty instead of being undefined.

Comment: An empty group is pretty much same as undefined/null. It is already a complex regex so we should avoid more tweaking.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution to split your path is to use regex group ([Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/w53YBa/2)):

Regex explanation with `'c:\foo\bar\baz.txt'`:

- The first thing is the drive: `(?<drive>[a-z]:)` -> `'c:'`
- The last thing is the file: `(?<file>(?<fname>\\w+)(?:\.(?<fext>\w+))?)`

  - `(?<fname>\\w+)` -> `'baz'`
  - `(?<fext>\\w+)` -> `'txt'`
- Then the parent path is `drive` + a repetion of `\\\w+\\?`:
  `(?<ppath>(?<drive>[a-z]:)(?:\\\w+\\?)+)`

So the full path is `drive + parent path + file`:
`(?<fullpath>(?<ppath>(?<drive>[a-z]:)(?:\\\w+\\?)+)(?<file>(?<fname>\w+)(?:\.(?<fext>\w+))?)$)`

```js
// Example without group
const path = 'c:\\foo\\bar\\baz.txt';
const regex = /([a-z]:)((?:\\?\w+\\)+)((\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?)/;
const found = path.match(regex);

// console.log(found); // Array ["c:\foo\bar\baz.txt", "c:", "\foo\bar\", "baz.txt", "baz", "txt"]
console.log('Root name:\t' + found[1]); // drive
console.log('Parent path:\t' + found[1]+found[2]); // Parent path
console.log('Filename:\t' + found[3]); // File name
console.log('Stem:\t\t' + found[4]); // Stem
console.log('Extension:\t' + found[5]); // Extension
```

```java
// Java example with group
String s = "c:\\foo\\bar\\baz.txt";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<fullpath>(?<ppath>(?<drive>[a-z]:)(?:\\\\\\w+\\\\?)+)(?<file>(?<fname>\\w+)(?:\\.(?<fext>\\w+))?)$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Path:\t\t" + m.group("fullpath"));
    System.out.println("Root name:\t" + m.group("drive"));
    System.out.println("Parent path:\t" + m.group("ppath"));
    System.out.println("Filename:\t" + m.group("file"));
    System.out.println("Stem:\t\t" + m.group("fname"));
    System.out.println("Extension:\t" + m.group("fext"));
}
/* OUTPUT */
Path:           c:\foo\bar\baz.txt
Root name:      c:
Parent path:    c:\foo\bar\
Filename:       baz.txt
Stem:           baz
Extension:      txt
```

Comment: It seems it use some features from C++, right? I need just a regex that I can use on it's own.

Comment: @johnc.j. sorry, it's Java, I write it for my test, but I also give you the link on regex101. Maybe you want an explanation of this regex ?

Comment: Also a substring method is possible. But if it's just a regex without language, I can edit my answer

Comment: This would be useful :)

Comment: @johnc.j. Done ;)

Comment: Named groups are cool, but the version you have posted doesn't work for filenames without an extension, e.g. `c:\foo\bar\baz`. :)

Comment: @johnc.j. Fixed the filename without extension